# How to check, How did my commit got into someone else's branch?

Tags: git, github

A person complained about why is my commit in their branch. It is showing in the diff with the master as my commit is yet to be merged into master. And I checked all my terminal history and it has got no command that I ran related to their branch. What are the possible sources that my commit got into his branch? How to check.

Is it possible that someone else might have pushed my commit to his branch? Does Github provide any info regarding this? Or He might have checked out his branch from my branch instead of master.

As far as pulling from the branch is concerned, I think it registers a new merge commit of the pull, so it would have reflected. but there is no merge commit.

Comment: It could be as simple as somebody creating a new branch off your branch/commit if it was already published. This is not necessarily something that you yourself had to do. But to answer your other question "find out how": no, that's not really possible

Comment: @knittl , Can I check the branch from which he checked out?

Comment: Yes, you can ask your colleague :)

Comment: It's the branch of your friend. He should know. Maybe he merged your branch into his. He can easily find out who commited anything in his branch. Tell him to find it out, and if he can show it was you, then he can complain :)